# Getting error stack trace when working NSPersistentCloudKitContainer in iOS

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, ios13, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I am trying to build a very basic app using Core Data and CloudKit.  I am logged into my CloudKit account on my Mac, and I followed the instructions to run the sample project that Apple provided on their [website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/synchronizing_a_local_store_to_the_cloud).

Using the sample project as a guide, I tried to build a simpler app using the instructions provided [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit).

However, after building trying to run my sample project, I get the following error stack trace in my console:

```
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitOptionsValidator validateOptions:andStoreOptions:error:](35): Validating options: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegateOptions: 0x60000097f960> containerIdentifier:iCloud.com.cybermedia.CloudKitTest1 initializeSchema:YES ckAssetThresholdBytes:<null> operationMemoryThresholdBytes:<null> useEncryptedStorage:NO automaticallyDownloadFileBackedFutures:NO automaticallyScheduleImportAndExportOperations:YES skipCloudKitSetup:NO preserveLegacyRecordMetadataBehavior:NO useDaemon:YES apsConnectionMachServiceName:<null> containerProvider:<PFCloudKitContainerProvider: 0x600002f602e0> scheduler:<null> notificationListener:<null> containerOptions:<null>
storeOptions: {
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptionsKey = "<NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions: 0x600002d73960>";
    NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey = 1;
    NSPersistentStoreMirroringOptionsKey =     {
        NSPersistentStoreMirroringDelegateOptionKey = "<NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20>";
    };
}
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _setUpCloudKitIntegration](355): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20>: Successfully enqueued setup request.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest](1854): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20>: Checking for pending requests.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest]_block_invoke(1866): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20>: Executing: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegateSetupRequest: 0x60000232c2a0> 6D32A278-F996-438D-AA8D-950F438F6402
2019-07-06 01:10:45.443340-0400 CloudKitTest1[14002:3818396] [error] error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _performSetupRequest:]_block_invoke(769): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20>: Failed to set up CloudKit integration for store: <NSSQLCore: 0x600001274000> (URL: file:///Users/fsyed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2A838B6E-EF14-4F54-9230-7B747A6DDE9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/249463B2-7348-4DBA-9739-0DDEB0ECBA10/Library/Application%20Support/CloudKitTest1.sqlite)
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134400 "Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount).}
CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _performSetupRequest:]_block_invoke(769): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20>: Failed to set up CloudKit integration for store: <NSSQLCore: 0x600001274000> (URL: file:///Users/fsyed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2A838B6E-EF14-4F54-9230-7B747A6DDE9B/data/Containers/Data/Application/249463B2-7348-4DBA-9739-0DDEB0ECBA10/Library/Application%20Support/CloudKitTest1.sqlite)
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134400 "Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount).}
2019-07-06 01:10:45.444373-0400 CloudKitTest1[14002:3818396] [error] error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate recoverFromError:](1259): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20> - Attempting recovery from error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134400 "Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount).}
CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate recoverFromError:](1259): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20> - Attempting recovery from error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134400 "Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount).}
2019-07-06 01:10:45.445456-0400 CloudKitTest1[14002:3818396] [error] error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _recoverFromError:withMonitor:](1398): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20> - Failed to recover from error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134400 "Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount).}
Recovery encountered the following error: (null)
CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _recoverFromError:withMonitor:](1398): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20> - Failed to recover from error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134400 "Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to initialize without an iCloud account (CKAccountStatusNoAccount).}
Recovery encountered the following error: (null)
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _finishedRequest:withResult:](1883): Finished request: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegateSetupRequest: 0x60000232c2a0> 6D32A278-F996-438D-AA8D-950F438F6402 with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x600002304ea0>
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest](1854): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20>: Checking for pending requests.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest]_block_invoke(1869): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x600001c7dc20>: No more requests to execute.
```

I keep getting the error:

```
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to initialize without an iCloud account
```

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sign in to your iCloud account on the simulator